# case-insensitive SCOM Rule expression

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scom, system-center

I have a Rule watching the Application Log for Event 17137 (database starting up).  A minor annoyance is that, whenever an instance is failed over, we see alerts fire from both the node and the instance for the same instance starting up.  I'd like to de-duplicate these with an expression filter on the data source.  I currently use

```
Logging Computer Equals $Target/Property[Type="Windows!Microsoft.Windows.Computer"]/DNSName$
```

However, I'm worried about cases where the `Logging Computer` string's character case differs from that of the `DNSName` property.  E.g., "foo1.my.domain" won't equal "FOO1.my.domain".

Is there a "toLower" or similar function that I can use to ensure that this expression is case-insensitive?

For reference: System Center Operations Manger 2007 v6.0.6278.0

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Override the rule's Enabled state for the "Windows Computers" group, so you only target the database instances?